# Dig timeout option don't work

Tags: dig

When I try either of these commands they do not stop after 5 seconds:

```
$ dig +time=5 @hii.com hello.me
```

-or-

```
$ dig @hii.com hello.me +time=5
```

What is the correct way to use this option?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The timeout value is per try so setting a `+time=5` would result in a 15 seconds delay as the default for `+tries` is `3`. If you set `+tries=1` then your command will timeout in 5 seconds e.g.

```
time dig +time=5  @hii.com hello.me

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-16.P1.el5_7.1 <<>> +time=5 @hii.com hello.me
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

real    0m15.017s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.011s
```

or with a `tries=1`

```
 time dig +time=5 +tries=1 @hii.com hello.me

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-16.P1.el5_7.1 <<>> +time=5 +tries=1 @hii.com hello.me
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

real    0m5.015s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was planning to stop the query by php actually and it was originally from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281060/limit-php-execution-time but dig option is more simple and efficient. Thanks again.

Comment: So `+tries` is acting as `+time`'s iterator inside the dig command?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig